# Installing PHPMyAdmin using Chef

Tags: phpmyadmin, chef-infra

I'm trying to setup PHPMyAdmin on a chef client, however it keeps erroring on build, & can't work out why.

Here's my run list of the node...

```
"recipe[networking_basic]",
"recipe[apache2]",
"recipe[chef-php]",
"recipe[chef-php::fpm]",
"recipe[php]",
"recipe[mysql]",
"recipe[phpmyadmin]"
```

And here's the error I'm getting...

```
FATAL: Saving node information to /srv/chef/file_store/failed-run-data.json
ERROR: Exception handlers complete
FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /srv/chef/file_store/chef-stacktrace.out
FATAL: NameError: Cannot find a resource for php_fpm on ubuntu version 12.04
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from he author of the cookbook, advising to use the chef-php cookbook instead of the normal php one, as it supersedes it.

I used the chef-php cookbook, but rename it to 'php' & all worked fine then.

Comment: How did you rename the cookbook "chef-php"?

Comment: Sorry Arnlen, I can't remember now.  It was some time ago now.

Answer (score 0):

You should post at least stacktrace from /srv/chef/file_store/chef-stacktrace.out, but most probably you are trying to use provider php_fpm in cookbook that does not have include_recipe "chef-php" in it.

Corresponding code can look like:

```
php_fpm 'phpmyadmin' do
  action :add
  user 'phpmyadmin'
  group 'phpmyadmin'
  socket true
  socket_path '/tmp/phpmyadmin.sock'
  socket_perms "0666"
  start_servers 2
  min_spare_servers 2
  max_spare_servers 8
  max_children 8
  terminate_timeout (node['php']['ini_settings']['max_execution_time'].to_i + 20)
  value_overrides({ 
    :error_log => "#{node['php']['fpm_log_dir']}/phpmyadmin.log"
  })
end
```

But it misses line

```
include_recipe "chef-php"
```

just before this code block

And don't forget to declare dependencies on chef-php cookbook in metadata.rb, as:

```
depends "chef-php"
```

Finally, I would suggest not to use forks from official cookbooks - you'll lose more when you'll try to maintain it